# Lens correction in Matlab

Tags: matlab, calibration

With [camera calibration Toolbox](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/vision/single-camera-calibration.html) in MATLAB, it looks like it corrects the lens distortion only for images that had checkerboards... I did the training part to get the [camera parameters](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/cameraparameters-class.html) from a data set of images with checkerboard with camera calibration app in MATLAB. and the lens correction for those images works perfectly. But when I apply the same camera parameters (that I got previousely) on others images with no checkerboard it does not give corrected images.

```
originalImage = imread('nochecherboard.jpg');
undistortedImage = undistortImage(originalImage, cameraParams);
```

the output
[image]

I don't know what I'm doing it wrong!! or already the MATLAB app does work only with checkerbord images???. Any help please !!!

Comment: Were the photos taken with the same lenses in the same setup?

Comment: Yes, the training data with the checkerboard and the images that I want to correct are taken under the same conditions ( same lens, same setup,...)